# Filter lines of a file through partial matches in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, filter

I have a file that contain redundant Git statements, like this:

```
git fetch
git checkout foo
git checkout bar
git checkout baz
git merge origin/baz
```

The checkout statements are redundant, and I would like to keep only the last one, so that the file ends up looking like this:

```
git fetch
git checkout baz
git merge origin/baz
```

I can only use Bash script. How could I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `awk` command:

```
tac input.txt | awk '{cmd = $1$2}; cmd != last; {last = cmd}' | tac
```

result:

```
git fetch
git checkout baz
git merge origin/baz
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` has a convenient way of printing the last occurrence of a pattern in a line:

```
sed '/checkout/h; $!d; x' file
```

Which, in your case would extract the string `git checkout baz`.

You can then use this in a script, save the `sed` output to a variable, and use it to print out all the lines which you specify:

```
file=$1
line=$(sed '/checkout/h; $!d; x' $file)
sed -n "/checkout/!p;/$line/p" $file
```

The last `sed` states, print all lines that do not contain `checkout`, as well as the one that contains the output from the first `sed` command.